# Crosstab with sub values in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, crosstab

I have this table called **tblCat**:

```
ID     Desc
1      Category A
2      Category B
3      Category C
```

The second table is **tblItem**

```
ID     Desc      Cat_Id
1      Item 1    1
2      Item 2    1
3      Item 3    2
4      Item 4    2
5      Item 5    3
6      Item 6    3
```

*Cat_id is the join-key for tblCat.*

The third one is tblItemDetail

```
ID   Loc    Item_Id   ItemValue     ValueDesc
1    S1     Item 1    Color         Black
2    S1     Item 1    Brand         ABC
3    S1     Item 1    Status        Ready
4    S1     Item 1    Discontinue   False
5    S1     Item 2    Color         White
6    S1     Item 2    Brand         XYZ
7    S1     Item 2    Status        Ready
8    S1     Item 2    Discontinue   False
9    S2     Item 3    Color         White
10   S2     Item 3    Brand         ABC
11   S2     Item 3    Status        Out-of-stock
12   S2     Item 3    Discontinue   True
```

I can build a crosstab for 1 single column value with this SQL:

```
select tbl.Loc, tbl.ItemValue, tbl.Item1, tbl.Item2, tbl.Item3,
tbl.Item4, tbl.Item5, tbl.Item6
from crosstab(
'select Loc, Item_Id, ItemValue, ValueDesc
from tblItemDetail',
'select Item_Id
from tblItemDetail
group by Item_Id'
) tbl(Loc text, ItemValue text, Item1 text, Item2 text, Item3 text, Item4 text,
Item5 text, Item6 text,);
```

And the result will be :

```
Loc    ItemValue     Item 1   Item 2   Item 3   Item 4   Item 5   Item 6
S1     Color         Black    White
S1     Brand         ABC      XYZ
S1     Status        Ready    Ready
S1     Discontinue   False    False
S2     Color                           White
S2     Brand                           ABC
S2     Status                          Out-of-Stock
S2     Discontinue                     True
```

But how to create a crosstab query to show this result?

```
                          Cat A            Cat B              Cat C
Loc    ItemValue     Item 1   Item 2   Item 3   Item 4   Item 5   Item 6
S1     Color         Black    White
S1     Brand         ABC      XYZ
S1     Status        Ready    Ready
S1     Discontinue   False    False
S2     Color                           White
S2     Brand                           ABC
S2     Status                          Out-of-Stock
S2     Discontinue                     True
```

In short, I want to know how to build a crosstab which having 2 columns level.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work.

Comment: I have create a crosstab by using tablefunc, and already able to show one level of column, which is Item N in the above sample. But I don't know how to create a higher column level above it.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Already update my question. Thanks for reminding. :)

Comment: Can PostgreSQL really return result sets with some columns combined into, what, column groups/subsets? I'd think that would need to be the application's job. However, I believe it should be possible to return the columns `Item 1`, `Item 2`, `Item 3` etc. under the names of `Category A Item 1`, `Category A Item 2`, `Category B Item 3` etc. You'd just need to use joins in the `crosstab` subqueries.

Comment: @AndriyM Thank you for your suggestion. I am using BIRT, and already able to do it.